PAM8403 power Vdd and power GND different from Vdd and GND?
This little class-D amplifier PAM8403 will work in Vdd 3.3, good for being fed by an ESP32 on the signals. But it has different Power Vdd and Power GND pins and can also work with 5 V at which it can achieve up to 5 W output on a 4 Ohm speaker.
I wonder if I can supply PVdd with 5 V while the normal Vdd will be on 3.3 V, and achieve the higher output power with the same 3.3 V input signal?
Another thing I find surprising is that it wants a coupling capacitor on the input, but it says the input can only take -0.3 V to (Vdd + 0.3 V), but after the coupling capacitor feeding an input between 0 and 3.3V will result in an input -1.65 V to +1.65 V. How does this square?
PS: I am intending to use that chip on my own designed board.

We don't know what board with that chip you have, and what does the schematics of the board look like, to give you an answer how to use it. At least link to the product you bought, or a manual, or take a photo for reverse engineering it. For the question about input signal, please link to chip datasheet.

If it expects a coupling capacitor on the input, the module probably has a suitable bias circuit to keep the signal after the capacitor at the correct voltage for proper operation.

Gunther, the edit you made did not really improve the question. Also a chip by the name of PAM803 does not seem to exist, is it a typo?

The data sheet mentions always a single supply and never indicates you can use different voltages for VDD and PVDD. It is assumed that the voltages must be same but there are just three supply pins and three ground pins, one set for sensitive analog circuits, one set for left output stage and one set for right output stage.
Also the analog input signal will never be 3.3V. You can freely use 5V supply. The typical gain for analog signal is 24 dB. That's a gain of 15.85. It means that for 5 Vpp output amplitude, you only need 0.315 Vpp input amplitude. The gain is adjustable, but it makes no sense to bring it down so low that you need a 3.3V input for 5V output to speaker.
So even if it were possible to use two different supplies for the chip, there is no benefit or need for it, and the one single supply covers all needs.
Also the innards of the chip are clear. It accepts absolute maximum values between -0.3V and VDD+0.3V. In practice the input voltage needs to be within 0V and VDD.
But the input stage is inverting op-amp configuration with bias to half supply.
So at the chip, if you have 3.3V supply, the input pin biases itself to 1.65V, and your signal can be -1.65V and +1.65V around that bias. That's an amplitude of 3.3V.
When the required capacitor is added between audio connector and chip input, the audio can also have amplitude of 3.3V, but audio between devices have 0V bias. The capacitor is to block DC between devices, allowing the chip to have the half-VDD DC bias and the other device on the other side of the capacitor to have any other DC bias, typically 0V.
But as mentioned above, the 24dB gain means you only need about 0.3V amplitude at the chip input.
Feel free to use that chip but use it according to the data sheet.

So, I can run it on 5 V then and supply a much lower input. If I only need 0.3 Vpp on the input pin, but my DAC output is 3.3 Vpp, then should I put a potentiometer here for volume control and reduction of input voltage so we don't get distortion?

@GuntherSchadow If your DAC outputs 3.3V, you must put a potentiometer for volume control, or otherwise divide the voltage to 0.3V, but it will still be the maximum output level, loudest possible before it clips and distorts. Likely driving the 5W you mentioned into 4 ohm speaker. With a speaker with not-very-good sensitivity of 80 dB per watt, that's 94 dB at 1 meter distance. You likely want less volume than the device is capable of.
